# Spring mvc: правильный package для POJO, используемых в services?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Я разрабатываю MVC приложение на Spring Boot, вот структура его пакетов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `domain` хранятся JPA маппинги на таблички, а также POJO для Redis. В пэкадже `repository` находятся Spring Data DAO для работы с доменной моделью, пакет `services` хранит service-layer и работает с DAO, а `controller` - REST контроллеры, работающие с сервисами.

Но обычно сервису недостаточно работать с моделью из `domain`. Сервис что-то вычисляет (например, парси данные из интернета), складирует в свои pojo, и передает контроллеру. Например, класс `FeedPage`, который по сути POJO, агрегирует данные, вычисляемые `FeedService` и никак не связанный с базой данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какой пекадж я должен включать похожие классы:

1. Вынести в `domain`? (но в `domain` я храню entities для работы с DB и Redis),
2. Оставить в `services.feed`?
3. Создать под каждым сервисом пакет `model` и в него складировать похожие pojo-классы?

Answer (score 1):

Структура пакетов - это в первую очередь ваше личное удобство и удобство вашей команды. Если пакеты имеют понятную структуру, другим людям (да и вам самим через некоторое время) будет легче ориентироваться в коде и поддерживать его.  В то же время, нет принципиальных правил, говорящих что куда класть. Разумно  складывать классы, выполняющие связанные задачи (то есть имеющие высокое сцеплением - cohesion) в один пакет.

Если классов в пакете становится много, в пакет разбивается на вложенные пакеты по аналогичному принципу. Понятие "много" у каждого свое. Мне, например, достаточно десятка разношерстных классов, чтобы начать дробить пакет.

Конкретно по вашему вопросу я бы остановился на варианте 2. Если количество классов в `feed` увеличится, можно будет перейти к варианту 3 создать отдельный вложенный пакет (например, `dto`) для POJO, отдельный - для всяких helper-ов и утильных классов.

PS. Понятие `model` в именах пакетов обычно используют как синоним `domain` - для описания предметной области.